# Ambiguous recursive(?) overload call

Tags: c#, function, call, overloading, ambiguous

How can I solve this? How can I point to the exact overload that I would like to use?

```
    int A()
    {
        if (Environment.TickCount == 666)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }

    bool A()
    {
        if (A() == 0) //here's an error!
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: Overloads that differ only from the result type if not possible in C#.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The error is **The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties**. The only error I got! Declaring duplicate functions with different return values caused no error! So that's why I was confused, and belived that there's a way to point to exact function.

Comment: If only you searched for "c# member overloading", you'd have found the answer: `Changing the return type of a method does not make the method unique as stated in the common language runtime specification. You cannot define overloads that vary only by return type.`

Answer (score 2):

When you provide multiple methods with the same name, the method is said to be *overloaded*. You cannot overload methods on return type in C#: you need to give them different names or different parameter types. In your case, changing the name of the `bool A` to `bool B` will fix the problem:

```
int A()
{
    if (Environment.TickCount == 666)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

bool B()
{
    if (A() == 0) //No error here
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@dasblinkenlight is right. It is also good practice to name your functions descriptive names.

example: bool IsEnvironmentTickCount666(). The Is in the function name makes it easy for someone reading your code to see you are returning a bool